# Help finding generating function for this problem

Tags: combinatorics

find a generating function for the number of partitions of n into:

a) at most four summands

b) exactly four summands

Are these correct: (top is A and bottom is B)

[image: a]

[image: B]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_partitions

Comment: Your previous quesiton on partitions has the same answers because each partition is uniquely associated with its [conjugate partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)).